# How to make multipage book in Calaméo?

Tags: pdf, calameo

If I upload a PDF binder I get the correct amount of pages but with the content of the first page on each. If I upload a number of PDFs separately it just creates a new publication for each PDF.

Would anyone know how to correctly publish a multipage book with Calaméo from PDFs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was going on. I was exporting them from Adobe Illustrator as large PDFs (30mb) I downsized them using the print option (0.3mb) and all is ok now